# Multiple Inheritance in Node js with constructor set in parent class

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

How can I set constructor in parent class and call the object in class inherited from parent class.

parent class:

```
var request = resuire('request');
var a = function(options) {
   if(!(this instanceof a)) {
     return new a(options);
   }
   var self = this;
   self.id = math.random();
   self.baseUrl = 'http://example.com/';
   self.options = options || {uri: self._baseUrl};
}

a.prototype._request = function reqest(options, callback){
   var self = this;
   request(options, function(err, res, body){
      self._determineResponse(err, res, body, function(){
         return body;
      }, callback);
   }
}
```

Child class:

```
var util = require('util');
var a    = require('a');
var b = function(){
    var self = this;  
}

b.prototype.auth(username, password, callback) {
   // access parent method (private or public) here to perform request
   a._request .... something
}

util.inherits(b, a);
```

Query:

- How to set parent constructor
- best way to access parent method

Comment: Put the `inherits()  call before the first attachment to `prototype` or you will overwrite it.